# Swift 4 Pinch-to-Zoom with view on scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift4

If I pinch the simulator, it does not work! I want to zoom in and out )=

Here is my Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    let onView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.delegate = self

        scrollView.contentSize.width = 10000
        scrollView.contentSize.height = 10000

        onView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)

        scrollView.addSubview(onView)

        for _ in 1...1000{

            let x = arc4random_uniform(10000)
            let y = arc4random_uniform(10000)

            let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: Int(x), y: Int(y), width: Int(150), height: Int(100)))
            btn.backgroundColor = .red
            self.board.addSubview(btn)

        }

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0

    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return scrollView
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors did you find? What in your code is it that you didn't understand? How did you debug it? 

Could you please specify some more details rather then "Can you fix it for me?".

Comment: If I pinch with alt, it doesn't zoom and I even can't scroll anymore

Comment: it should be` return onView` inside `viewForZooming ` method. nor scroll view